# Proving the Limit of a Sequence of without the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show:

> $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sin^n(x) = 0. $$

I showed this using the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). I want other methods to prove it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $a \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$,

Let $d = cos(a) < 1$

$0 \le \sin(x)^n \le d^n$ for any $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}-a]$, and $0 \le \sin(x)^n \le 1$ for any $x \in [\frac{\pi}{2}-a,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

$0 \le \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(x)^n \text{ dx} \le (\frac{\pi}{2}-a) d^n + a \to a$ as $n \to \infty$

$0 \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(x)^n \text{ dx} \le a$

Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(x)^n \text{ dx} = 0$

Answer (score 2):

The sequence converges uniformly to zero over any interval bounded away from $\pi/2$. Thus given $\varepsilon>0$ choose an interval $[0,\eta]\subsetneq [0,\pi/2]$ so that the integral over the remaining interval is tiny, and use uniform convergence over what remains.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the [$\beta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) function which gives the answer

> $$ I=\,{\frac {\sqrt {\pi}\,\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \right) }{2\,\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}+1 \right) }}.$$

Now, we appeal to the Stirling approximation

> $$ n! =\Gamma(n+1) \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n  $$

to finish the problem.

**Note:** The $\beta$ function is given by

> $$ \beta(x,y) = 2\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin\theta)^{2x-1}(\cos\theta)^{2y-1}\,\mathrm{d}\theta, \qquad \mathrm{Re}(x)>0,\ \mathrm{Re}(y)>0. $$

Comment: Isn't it much harder to prove Stirling's approximation than the dominated convergence theorem? Haha..

Comment: @user21820: Have you read the title of the question?

Comment: If I haven't, I wouldn't be able to mention DCT, but I would have thought that people usually want more elementary methods when avoiding DCT. Nothing wrong with your method of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use monotone convergence where $\sin^n(x)$ converges to $0$ almost everywhere on the interval $[0,\pi /2]$.  This is of course extending the notion of monotone convergence to a decreasing sequence of measurable functions.  I know this isn't a great answer but it's my thoughts on the issue.

Comment: This is perfectly correct, but it may be argued that this is essentially what lies behind the dominated convergence theorem, so if we want to avoid any such measure theory approach we will need to use some specific properties of the given function.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate this explicitly; cases vary with even and odd.  Do the following.
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^n(x)\,dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{n-1}(x)\sin(x)\,dx$$
Integrate by parts with $dv = \sin(x)\,dx$.  Use the fact that $\sin^2(x) 
+ \cos^2(x)$ to get rid of the $\cos^2(x).$  Now solve for the original integral and get a nice reduction formula.