# Evaluate limit integrate: $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sin^{n} x dx}$

Tags: integration, limits

I know,
when n is even,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sin^{n} x dx = \frac {(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}\frac {\pi}{2} $$

and n is odd,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sin^{n} x dx = \frac {(2m)!!}{(2m+1)!!} $$

But when let limit n to infinite, how can I get the limit, or if the limit exists.

--

I find a good way to solve the limit:$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}
$$

as we know,
$2 =\frac{1+3}{2} > \sqrt{1 \cdot 3}$ , so $2n = \frac{(2n-1)+(2n+1)}{2} > \sqrt{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$

so,
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{\sqrt{1 \cdot 3}\cdots \sqrt{(2n-3)(2n-1)}\sqrt{2n-1}}{\sqrt{1\cdot 3} \cdots \sqrt{(2n-3)(2n-1)} \sqrt{(2n-1)(2n+1)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}} \to 0 (n \to \infty)$$

Comment: How big is sine on $[0,\pi/2)$? What happens if you keep taking powers of that?

Comment: See [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1166333p5574721).

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649484/proving-the-limit-of-a-sequence-of-without-the-dominated-convergence-theorem

Answer (score 1):

More generally, for any real $n>-1$ the formula is: $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)\mathrm d x =\dfrac{\surd\pi}{2}\cdotp\dfrac{\Gamma(\tfrac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\tfrac{n+2}{2})}$$

Now, consider whether the ratio of these Gamma functions will converge--and if so where to--as $n$ increases, ....

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously zero. Think of the graph of $\sin^nx$ with $n$ going to infinity. How the area under the $y=\sin^nx $ changes accordingly

Comment: Also, clearly $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(n)!!}{(n+1)!!}=0$ so

Comment: Yea, that too; but I tried to make trivial things simple so even a layman can understand.

Comment: @GrahamKemp  $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\frac {m!!}{(m+1)!!}} = 0$ seem not so easy to figure out.

Comment: No, it's easy to see the trend.  As $n$ gets larger, then $n!!$ becomes much smaller than $(n+1)!!$, so...

Comment: It is easy only if you can evaluate that definite integral easily. (It is easy for me but...)